# spree_paypal_express - Spree::Admin::PaymentsControllerDecorator (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, spree-paypal-express

I'm searching one solution for my question on web, but probably no one had the same problem.

Before deploying my spree project to the cloud, i'm trying to run it in my local host with `RAILS_ENV=production`, but I always receive the same error:

> expected file
>   /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/better_spree_paypal_express-181cce8bcd14/app/controllers/spree/admin/payments_controller_decorator.rb
>   to define constant Spree::Admin::PaymentsControllerDecorator, but
>   didn't (NameError)

I am having this problem only on production environment and I realize this started to happen when I added the `spree_paypal_expresss` gem.

Using Rails 6 and Spree 4.0 with sqlite just to test.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Actually I don't know what the real cause about it, but the downgrading the spree version to 3.7 the problem doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [thred](https://spree-commerce.slack.com/archives/C0HUDSW5V/p1575972628150300?thread_ts=1575972628.150300) on Spree's Slack channel, 
you should use https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero for PayPal integration on Spree.